# Hibernate User String field for @OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables in Mysql, one is `user` and another is `userRoles`, both are existing tables in the project. The Current foreign key is `login_id` (varchar).

Can I create `@ManyToOne` mapping in these two tables, I get the error:

> getInt() can not parse to 'userLoginName'.

TABLES:

User:

```
user_id int(11)
login_name varchar(50)
password varchar(50)
status varchar(1)
```

user_roles:

```
user_role_id int(11)
login_name varchar(50) #fk
user_role_name varchaar(100)
```

Is there any way to do the mapping with String if not any other solution? I can not change its data type because of the existing project with the same database. I am creating supporting project with Hibernate.

Comment: can you post what you have in your entity classes?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to join by the `login_name` field.

Try this:

**User Roles entity**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "login_name", referencedColumnName = "login_name")
private User user;
```

**User entity**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserRole> roles;
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Maciej Kowalski is correct.

You can do it this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "LOGIN_NAME", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String loginName;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 64)
    private char[] password

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private Status status = Status.ACTIVE;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = UserRole.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE_MAPS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "LOGIN_NAME")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")})
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
    //... getter and setter
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLE", uniqueConstraints = {@javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"USER_ROLE_NAME"})})
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long roleId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ROLE_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    //... getter and setter
}
```